# Facebook API - get photos uploaded by user within a specific timespan

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to retrieve photos that user uploaded between a specific date/timespan ?

Eg. Photos uploaded between January 1, 2016 and January 10, 2016.

Comment: Maybe take a look in the API documentation, and add closest matches of function / method calls you found and ask / tell where something is missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no timespan filter on this endpoint. You can fetch all uploaded images for your user, and then filter the results on your own.

```
GET /{user-id}/photos?type=uploaded&fields=created_time
```